# When do SharePoint Online authentication tokens expire?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-online

I have a C# app which modifies files in SharePoint Online document libraries. The app authenticates with SharePoint Online using web requests and uses the returned cookies when calling web services. The app can run for several days (possibly even weeks for large file sets) as it churns through files. Do I need to worry about authentication tokens expiring once authentication is successful and the app is running?

This [article](http://mstechtalk.com/office-365-session-timeout-configuration/) mentions the session will timeout after 5 days of inactivity, but what if my app is still active?